# ruby equivalent of destructor

Tags: ruby, destructor, rubypython

I'm using [`RubyPython`](http://rubypython.rubyforge.org) to import a Python module. I am doing `RubyPython.start` in the constructor (`initialize`), and I suppose I should symmetrically do `RubyPython.stop` in the destructor, but unfortunately it seems that there is no destructor in Ruby:

```
class QDSHiveHelper
    def initialize
        RubyPython.start
        qds = RubyPython.import('blah')
        ...
    end
    def do_something
        qds.some_function
        ...
    end 
    def finalize
        RubyPython.stop
    end
end
```

Could someone please explain how to accomplish this? `ObjectSpace.define_finalize` seems to be discouraged and has some gotchas (can't use closure etc). I could also just leave `RubyPython` dangling and not call `stop` on it, but I don't know what could be the consequences. What's the best way out?

Comment: The "best way out" is to not call `RubyPython.start` in your constructor, where it will be invoked once per instance of your class. Instead, call it once per instance of your program.

Comment: meagar: if you could post an answer with this, I'll accept it. This is the indeed what works best for me.

Comment: Your question has been marked as a duplicate, so no new answers can be posted. Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a hook called [ObjectSpace.define_finalizer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-define_finalizer) that is called when an object is destroyed.

Comment: You mean 'ObjectSpace.define_finalizer' right?

Comment: Could you point me to an example that uses 'ObjectSpace.define_finalizer'?

Comment: Right, that was my mistake. See the top of the page I linked.